# Remove line breaks in wp_list_categories()?

Tags: template-tags

I am trying to output a list of categories per an article. I am using the following code,

`<?php wp_list_categories('child_of=270&style=none'); ?>`

(string) Style to display the categories list in. A value of list displays the categories as list items while none generates no special display method (the list items are separated by `<br>` tags).

How do I remove the stupid `<br />` after each output?

Frustrating how this code

`<?php the_category(', '); ?>`

Will output the links without a line break...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came to a solution for this by reviewing the [Wordpress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories). The trick is to turn off the automatic echo of wp_list_categories, and then use str_replace(). My example follows:

```
<?php $variable = wp_list_categories('child_of=270&style=none&echo=0'); ?>
<?php $variable = str_replace('<br />', '', $variable); ?>
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

The only real change in your query is the inclusion of "echo=0" which will return the information in a variable rather than just displaying it.

The real work is done by str_replace() which looks for any `<br />` tags and removes them from the string. Then just echo out the updated string and no more breaks!

Comment: what an elegant, and effective solution. i am quickly learning how viable `str_replace` is becoming with WP. TY!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer above, I found a solution that allows for even more customisation of the  output of wp_list_categories. I'm using this for showing all terms in a taxonomy.

```
   <?php
        $args = array(
          'taxonomy'     => 'place',
          'orderby'      => 'name',
          'style'        => 'list',
          'show_count'   => 0,
          'pad_counts'   => 0,
          'hierarchical' => 1,
          'title_li'     => '',
          'exclude'      => '28',
          'echo'         => '0'

        );
```

As opposed to the example above which requires 'style' => 'none', I'm using 'style' => 'list', outputting an unordered list with `<li>` and `<ul>` tags but no `<br />` tags.

Then the PHP command `strip_tags` selectively strips all html tags. This would of course also work for stripping the `<br />` tag when using 'style' => 'none'.

```
    <?php $variable = wp_list_categories($args); ?>
    <?php $variable = strip_tags( $variable, '<a>' ); ?>
    <?php echo $variable; ?>
```

The second parameter in `strip_tags` are the allowable tags, i.e. tags that are kept in the code. So it's keeping the `<a>` tag to preserve all links, and bingo!

Now the deluxe version allows, for example, to style child terms differently to their parents:

```
    <?php $variable = wp_list_categories($args); ?>
    <?php $variable = strip_tags( $variable, '<a><ul>' ); ?>
    <?php $variable = str_replace('ul', 'span', $variable); ?>
    <?php echo $variable; ?>
```

Firstly this keep the `<a>` tag and the `<ul>` tag which always has the class "children". Then it replaces 'ul' with 'span' and the tag will read `<span class="children">`. Now all list tags are gone and you're free to add a CSS style for the class "children".

Comment: Why not extend the category walker and produce the output you need, instead of doing expensive string matching and replacing?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple way to get the links in line is to output with li elements so don't set style to "none".

Then you can just set display: inline; on "li" elements in your container.

much cleaner that way